# How to apportion between BatchInserterIndex cache and MMIO?

Tags: memory, configuration, lucene, neo4j, memory-mapped-files

In a batch insertion using lucene indexes, given a large set of nodes and relations such that the node and relationship store cannot fit completely in mapped memory (hence the need for lucene index caching), how should one divide memory between MMIO and lucene index caches to achieve optimal performance? Having read the documentation, I am already somewhat familiar with how to divide memory within the mapped-memory schema. I am interested in the overall allotment of memory between MMIO and the lucene caches. Since I am working on a prototype with what hardware happens to be available, and the future resources and data volume are undetermined, I would prefer the answer to be in general terms (I think this would also make the answer more useful to the rest of Neo4j community too.) So it would be good if I could pose the question like this:

Given

rwN nodes and rwR relationships that are written and must be read later in the batch insertion,
woN nodes and woR relationships that are only written,
G gigabytes of RAM (not including what is required for the operating system)

What is the optimal division of G between lucene index caches and MMIO?

If more details are needed I can supply them for my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

**All these considerations are only relevant for importing (multiple) billions of nodes and relationships**

Usually when you do lookups it depends on the "hot dataset size" of your index lookups.

By default that's all nodes but if you know your domain better, you can probably devise some paging that results in smaller needed caches (e.g. by pre-sorting your input data for relationship creation by start and end-node lookup-property) then you have kind of a moving window over your node data during which each node is accessed frequently.

I usually even sort by min(start,end).

Usually you try to use most of the RAM for mmio mapping of the rel-store and node store. The property stores are only written to but the others have to be updated as well.

The index cache lookup is only a HashMap behind the scenes, so quite wasteful. What I found to work better is to use a different approach, e.g. a multi-pass one.

- use an string-array put all your lookup properties in there, sort it and use the array index (Arrays.binarySearch) as node-id then the lookup only in that array is quite efficient
- another way is using a multi-pass on the source data so you already create the node-ids that are needed for the rels as part of the source, Friso and Kris from Xebia did something like that in their [hadoop based solution](http://blog.xebia.com/2013/01/17/combining-neo4j-and-hadoop-part-ii/) esp. the [monotonically increasing parallel id's](http://waredingen.nl/monotonically-increasing-row-ids-with-mapredu)

Comment: Thank you! This cleared things up a great deal. I have switched to a cache less solution wherein I generate my own node IDs and never have to read anything when I load. Huge time savings.